# Map chopped off across 180degree line from QGIS to Mapbox

Tags: qgis, mapbox

I am currently exporting a geojson data from qgis to mapbox studio. My area map covers and crosses the 180 degree line across the Pacific ocean. I tried exporting using CRS setting EPSG:4326 and EPSG:3832 (Pacific Disaster Center) to no luck as both settings cuts and only shows the first half of the area.

Is there a way that I can export the geojson without being cut off?

[image]

Area should be this:

[image]

Comment: Does QGIS export one polygon that crosses the dataline or two halves?

Comment: @user30184 I tried opening the one I exported from QGIS and it showed a complete shape and also I don't know yet how to manually split it in half. Checking the geojson output code itself, I can see that it's grouped in a single piece, not half.

Comment: Try this: in QGIS use layer - save as, then select format `geojson` (not the newline delimited). Change option RFC7946 into `YES`. If that does not help then saving GeoJSON into temporary file and converting it into new one with ogr2ogr by using option ´-wrapdateline` should split the geometry.

Comment: @user30184 The RFC7946 into YES setting did work. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the GeoJSON specification geometries which are crossing the dateline are not strictly forbidden but it is recommended that they are cut in two halves.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946

> In representing Features that cross the antimeridian,
> interoperability is improved by modifying their geometry.  Any
> geometry that crosses the antimeridian SHOULD be represented by
> cutting it in two such that neither part's representation crosses the
> antimeridian.

The original GeoJSON specification did not include the rule of splitting the geometries by the dateline. Selecting option `RFC7946 YES`forces QGIS to use the current specification and splitting.